# An ambiguous question on 2 balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Two balls A & B are at rest at the bottom of a hill.Sometime after ball A is given a kick up the hill, ball B is also given a kick up the hill. When ball B is going up the hill, ball A is already coming downhill. When they pass by each other what properties will they share in common?
The question is pretty ambiguous, so can anyone share their opinions..

Comment: This is a question about conservation of energy, as far as I can tell. I think you should be able to deduce your answer from this hint (but note that we are *not a homework site*, so questions like this are off-topic here).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

They will be at the same height. Assuming a hill of constant slope, they will both be experiencing the same acceleration. They will both also be balls.

Comment: It is frowned-upon here to directly answer homework-like questions.

Comment: You don't know that they have the same potential energy. They would have to have identical mass.